# How do I can search through uploaded files with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

How do I can search through uploaded files with Laravel by pattern?

```
I tried Storage::files('uploads/daisjdas09js_*')
```

do not works

I know, i can get all files as array and then filter out, also i can each upload register to database and then search from database.

Is worth it create table? Or array filter do not takes to much memory?

Laravel version is 5.3

Comment: Its here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#directories

Comment: i would create a table for that, i can't be sure from the doc if `Storage::files()` would get only the names not loading all files

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Thanks. I changed my structure to folders. And now "daisjdas09js" is as folder, and files inside is what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the doc at [FileSystem](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/filesystem#directories):

[image]

Its clear that, using `Storage::files()` would return the Files list in that directory as a string or file path/name:

given you something like:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "evaluation/.DS_Store"
  1 => "evaluation/sample.json"
  2 => "evaluation/sample_text.txt"
]
//note it excludes the subdirectories and files in subdirectories
```

If you want all the file lists also in subdirectories then use `Storage::allFiles($directory)`.

Since you now have it you can then do the check based on the returned values, then do the filter by your self.